# nodejs: imported function not returning value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function `checkIsDir` and I have imported it to the main file `cli.js` but I am unable to access the value which is been returned, in this case, it is `true`.

`checkIsDir.js`

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const listr = require('listr')

function checkIsDir(path) {
  const tasks = new listr([
    {
      title: 'Checking if path is a directory',
      task: () => {
        try {
          fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()
          // return true if the path is a directory
          return true
        }
        catch (err) {
          throw new Error(`Path ${path} is not a directory`)
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  tasks.run().catch(err => {
    throw new Error(err)
  })
}

module.exports = checkIsDir
```

`cli.js`

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const fs = require('fs')

const questions = require('./data/questions');
const checkIsDir = require('./lib/checkIsDir');
const spiltPath = require('./lib/splitPath');

const path = process.cwd();

inquirer.prompt(questions).then(async (answers) => {
  console.log(checkIsDir(answers.path))
  if (checkIsDir(answers.path) === true) {
    spiltPath(answers.path);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Oh no')
  }
});
```

[image: terminal output]

`splitPath.js`

```js
function spiltPath(path) {
  var spiltArray = path.split('/');
  var folderName = spiltArray[spiltArray.length - 1];
  console.log(folderName);
}

module.exports = spiltPath
```

Comment: `checkIsDir` does not return anything. The only `return` is in the function assigned to `task` but nothing in the main function itself.

Comment: @Kira - As @​VLAZ said, your function doesn't return anything, and since it's dealing with asynchronous processes, it *can't* return the result directly (just a promise of the result, just like `tasks.run` does).

Comment: Is their any way to return the value ?